# How to Get Sharepoint data?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have just started a Sharepoint, I would need items listed in Sharepoint 2013.

Please let me know is any rest service available to access data from sharepoint which I can store in my local db.

Please suggest me what are the best way to access data from it.

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: Is this SharePoint on-premise or online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 the REST API Endpoints are different.

It's more like this:
/_api/lists/getByTitle('Custom List')/Items

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff798339.aspx

For example:

```
http://localhost/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Parts(3)
```

The preceding URL returns the Parts list item with an ID value of 3 as an Atom feed.

Comment: What about authentication?